# Installing eclipse neon on windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying to install eclipse neon on my pc which has windows 10 64 bits.I downloaded the exe file from the oficial page:(https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe) but it wont run i dont know why.

I have java and jdk up to date but still cant make it run.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get any error/exception

Comment: IIRC, Neon installs and launches differently than previous Eclipse versions. Did you complete the installation steps listed here (click on the `Find out more` link): http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/? Specifically, did you get to [Step 5. Launch Eclipse)? It should allow you to assign the location where the launcher gets installed. If so, can you find that launcher location, open up a `command prompt` there, and run `eclipse`. If you get that far, what happens when you run it from the `cmd` prompt?

Comment: Im stuck in step 2 of the instalation guide.After i click in "run" in the security warning window nothing happens

Comment: Did you try to run it from command-line? Maybe the log would tell you more. My first guess is that it could be an issue with your Java installation.

Comment: I ran it from the command-line and got the same results no error message appear and nothing happens either.                                                                                       I dont know if is there an issue with my java instalation because I could perfectly use previous versions of eclipse.                                                                          Do i have to erase all old versions of eclipse from my pc before installing neon?

Comment: I've reinstalled java and jdk but i get no results,help please

Comment: Might be the issue in installation, >> Select Another Mirror.. make sure you are using mirror which close to your location and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1) create System variable:
JAVA_HOME   -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\

2) add to PATH  -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;

Answer (score 0):

It might be one of the reason that you are running two versions of JDKs, please check your JDK compatible version for Windows 10 - 64 bit.

please check the Java version first ...

from command prompt: **java -version**, you should see current java version running on your system like below :

***C:\Users\xxxxx>java -version

java version "1.8.0_121"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)***

if you could see the above msg, then check your java - system variable set to :

**JAVA_HOME**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
**PATH** : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin

Answer (score 0):

Try Eclipse **Oxygen** (newer than Neon). I had problems with the installer that the Eclipse team recommends, so I downloaded and extracted the zip file under "**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**" / "64 bit" on 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/ (direct link: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/1/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1-win32-x86_64.zip)

Then reference your Java version in the eclipse.ini file. Search for

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe
```

on https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for details.